# CSS Flexbox Spread the Column Items Equal Distance with Margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin

I am wondering how I create equal distance between items in the columns with margin.

My code looks like this:

```css
.App {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.about {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid black 3px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.userInput {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
  border: solid black 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.story {
  background-color: rgb(100, 149, 237);
  border: solid black 3px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='App'>
  <div class='userInput'>
  </div>
  <div class='Story'>
  </div>
  <div class='About'>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought applying this to "justify-content: space-around" to the App style would spread the div evenly across the page in respect to margin.

Answer (score 1):

You were close! **CSS is case sensitive** and your story and about section actually start with a capital letter. So you need to select `.Story` and `.About`. See code below.

```css
.App {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.About {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid black 3px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.userInput {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
  border: solid black 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.Story {
  background-color: rgb(100, 149, 237);
  border: solid black 3px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='App'>
  <div class='userInput'>
  </div>
  <div class='Story'>
  </div>
  <div class='About'>
  </div>
</div>
```